# Cucumber - continue in different value

Tags: javascript, cucumber, gherkin

I have step: "I see in "xyz" "123" that checks if in field "xyz" is value "123" and if not, then it fails..but i dont want in this case to fail..i would like to see that it has diferent value (for example "321) and continue...is it possible to add this feature? (its javascript).

Answer (score 0):

With as little information I have, I can see that you have a validation step that goes something like:

```
...
Then I validate the reservation id is "123"
...
```

I'd do the following:  implement the step to compare the expected vs actual, and log pass or fail or warning as desired.  example below:

Step definition:

```
@Then("^I validate the reservation id is \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void iValidateTheReservationIdIsSomething(String reservationID) throws Throwable {
    reservationPage.validateReservationId(reservationID);
}
```

and a ReservationPage class like:

```
...
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "foo")
WebElement reservationIDTxt;
...
public void validateReservationId(reservationID) {
    String actualReservationID = reservationIDTxt.getText();
    Log.logStepResult("stepName", "stepExpected", "stepActual", 
        reservationId.equals(actualReservationID) ? Result.Passed : 
            Result.Warning);
}
```

Hope this helps, or at least, include more detail.